# Setting a view's position programmatically

Tags: android, view

I have a floating action button that with a touchListener to move it across the screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and the code to move it:

```
floatingActionButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    positionX = view.getX() - event.getRawX();
                    positionY = view.getY() - event.getRawY();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    view.animate()
                            .x(event.getRawX() + positionX)
                            .y(event.getRawY() + positionY)
                            .setDuration(0)
                            .start();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("stored_position", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.putFloat("pos_x", positionX).apply();
                    editor.putFloat("pos_y", positionY).apply();
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

All works well, however I'm facing a challenge in setting the stored X and Y values in onCreate, the view is still in its original position:(This is what I've tried to do)

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("stored_position", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Float savedPositionX = sharedPreferences.getFloat("pos_x", 0);
    Float savedPositionY = sharedPreferences.getFloat("pos_y", 0);

    floatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);
    if (savedPositionX != 0 && savedPositionY != 0) {
        floatingActionButton.setX(savedPositionX);
        floatingActionButton.setY(savedPositionY);
   }

      //setTranslation has also not worked
```

How can I achieve the desired result?

Comment: did you try setting the position with animation property? like: ViewPropertyAnimator.animate(view).translationYBy(-yourY).translationXBy(-yourX).setDuration(0);

Comment: yes, that also hasn't worked

Comment: your trying this in onCreate? try in onResume after the view is created

Comment: That too isn't working, it should work in onCreate since I'm first checking if the values are stored in SharedPreferences

Comment: Just so I understand it clearly, you are having trouble accessing the coordinates from sharedPreferences, right?

Comment: No I can access them, but setting it to the view(FloatingActionButton) is not working, so the view remains in its original set position

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same call to position the View(FAB button).

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("stored_position", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Float savedPositionX = sharedPreferences.getFloat("pos_x", 0);
    Float savedPositionY = sharedPreferences.getFloat("pos_y", 0);

    floatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);
    if (savedPositionX != 0 && savedPositionY != 0) {
        //this is working i have tested 
        floatingActionButton.animate()
        .x(savedPositionX)
        .y(savedPositionY)
        .setDuration(0)
        .start()
   }
```

but the position of view will not be same as width/height ratio of portrait and landscape will be different.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you set the position of the view too early in the `OnCreate`. The solution should be as @medyas suggested, in screen `onResume` or you may use the so-called `OnGlobalLayoutListener` in your `onCreate` method like this.

```
fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    // obtain view
    val fab: FloatingActionButton = ...

    // setup observer that will "wait" till view is correctly laid out
    val observer = fab.viewTreeObserver
    observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {

        override fun onGlobalLayout() {
            observer.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)

            // TODO here run your "setup"
        }
    })
}
```